# How to click on a next-step button on Protractor E2E tests

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I have an AngularJs application, and I'm looking for an issue to click on a next-step button on my page. Here is the AngularJs code for the button :

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg single-line next-step next-step ng-   
 scope" button-submit="" ng-click="sign(); $showNextPanel()" type="submit" 
 ng-if="currentFormality.hasTouchScreen === false || 
 currentFormality.signatureType === SignatureType.PAPER" step-panel-next="">
 <span ng-transclude="">

<i class="icon icon-azf-arrow-down pull-right ng-scope"></i>
                            <span class="pull-right ng-binding ng-scope">
                                Passer à l'étape suivante
                            </span>
                        </span></button>`
```

I tried the following code :

My function :

```
export function nextStep(): webdriver.promise.Promise<any> {
let btnNextStep = element.all(by.css('.btn.next-step'));
return waitElementIsDisplayed(by.css('.btn.next-step'))
    .then(() => (
        btnNextStep.click()
    ))
    .then(() => {
        return Promise<boolean>((deferred) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                deferred.fulfill(true);
            }, 1500);
        })
    });
}
```

My code to click on the button :

```
        it('should go to next step', () => {
                promise
                    .then(() => (
                        nextStep()                          
                    ));
            });
```

But it doesn't work :(

Can you please help me ?

Comment: Can you share the website ? If it is button, use buttontext.

Comment: It's a website under construction. So not available through the internet.

Comment: `nextStep()` will again return a promise you have to resolve it.

Comment: I don't understand your answer Ram Pasala ?

Comment: The problem was resolved. the point was the closing "}" symbol which was  in the wrong place